# How to quickly access help pages for a particular plugin from inside Vim

Tags: vim

Trying out a lot of new plugins for Vim, I often found that in order to look up something in the documentation I need to go to my `.vim/bundle` directory and open up the readme file manually. That's pretty time-consuming, and I was wondering if there is an easier way to quickly access the help pages of a particular plugin without quitting your session or opening a new terminal window.

Sometimes I just give `:help <name of the plugin>` and it works, but that doesn't happen for all the plugins I have installed. Is there a way for getting it to work all the time?

Comment: Can you give an example of a plugin where it doesn't work?

Comment: I did a quick check going through `:scriptnames` output. Right now the `:h` command doesn't work, among others, with surround, tcomment and vim-multiple-cursors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to regenerate the *help tags database* via

```
:helptags ~/.vim/bundle/<pluginname>/doc
```

This should create / update a `tags` file in that directory, which the `:help` command picks up (based on `'runtimepath'`).

This assumes that the plugin provides a help file in Vim's help format (i.e. with tags marked `*tag*`). The Vimball install method does this automatically, BTW.

Comment: Wow, looks like this did the trick. I use Tim Pope's Pathogen as install method, wonder why it lacks such an important feature.

Comment: @zool pathogen provides `:Helptags` to regenerate all doc tag files